# Split based on Regex python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string like below

```
"‘‘Apple’’ It is create by Steve Jobs (He was fired and get hired) ‘‘Microsoft’’ Bill Gates was the richest man in the world ‘‘Oracle’’ It is a database company"
```

I am able to manage to use regex to create groups of Apple, Microsoft and Oracle by using `‘‘(.*?)’’` but how should I extract the other sentence part to list?

What I want to create

```
companyList = ['Apple','Microsoft','Oracle']

descriptionList = ['It is create by Steve Jobs (He was fired and get hired)','Bill Gates was the richest man in the world','It is a database company']
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: So, if the input is `‘‘Apple’’ or ‘‘AAPL’’ It is create by Steve Jobs (He was fired and get hired) ‘‘Microsoft’’ Bill Gates was the richest man in the world ‘‘Oracle’’ It is a database company`, what is the expected output? Also, can there be any `‘` or `’` inside `‘‘...’’`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `re.findall` with the following pattern:

```
‘‘(.*?)’’ (.*?)(?= ‘‘|$)
```

This will capture, in separate groups, the company name and description, for each match found in the input.  Note that we use the lookahead `(?= ‘‘|$)` as the end of the current description, which either occurs at the start of the next entry, or the end of the input.

```
inp = "‘‘Apple’’ It is create by Steve Jobs (He was fired and get hired) ‘‘Microsoft’’ Bill Gates was the richest man in the world ‘‘Oracle’’ It is a database company"
matches = re.findall('‘‘(.*?)’’ (.*?)(?= ‘‘|$)', inp)
companyList = [row[0] for row in matches]
descriptionList = [row[1] for row in matches]
print(companyList)
print(descriptionList)
```

This prints:

```
['Apple', 'Microsoft', 'Oracle']
['It is create by Steve Jobs (He was fired and get hired)',
 'Bill Gates was the richest man in the world', 'It is a database company']
```

Comment: Another way of getting the final lists (no double iteration): `companyList, desriptionList = (list(group) for group in zip(*matches))`